# JSON array filter does not apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, filter

I am trying to filter the data from an array, but it is throwing an error saying

> filter() is not function

Here is the code:

```
var selectedObject = [];
selectedObject= JSON.stringify(formsDataSource.data());
//console.log(selectedObject);

//var filtered = $.grep(selectedObject, function (el) {
//    return el.po_order_no = 18;
//});
//console.log((filtered));
if (selectedObject == undefined) {
    alert("Undefined");
} else {
    var data= selectedObject.filter(function (element) { return element.po_order_no = "18"; })
    alert("" + data);
}
```

I tried many things but it is still throwing an error. Any help?

Comment: `selectedObject= JSON.stringify(formsDataSource.data())` seems to imply that `selectedObject` is a string. A string does not have a `.filter` method. Although I note that you are doing this right after declaring it as an empty array. Is that intentional? Why overwrite it one line after declaring it?

Comment: I tried with .push().. No Error but no Data

Comment: why are you json.stringifying it? If formsDataSource.data() returns an array, just skip the stringify (maybe do it at the end of the function?)

Comment: formsDataSource.data() returns an [object, object, object] to make it readable I am using json.stringify()

Comment: sounds like [object, object, object] is what you want, json.stringify changes it into a string - you can't filter a string.

Comment: How could I filter Object?

Comment: [object, object, object] is an array of objects.  It looks like (looking at your filter function) each one has a property called `po_order_no`?

Comment: Yes, each has po_order_no..

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations :**

- > selectedObject= JSON.stringify(formsDataSource.data());

  This statement states that selectedObject is a string. A string does not have a `filter()` method.
- condition inside filter function should be `element.po_order_no == "18"` instead of `element.po_order_no = "18"`

**Solution :**

```js
var selectedObject = [
{
  "po_order_no": 18,
  "po_order_name": "abc"
},
{
  "po_order_no": 19,
  "po_order_name": "xyz"
}
];

if (selectedObject == undefined) {
    console.log("Undefined");
} else {
    var data = selectedObject.filter(element => element.po_order_no == "18")
    console.log(data);
}
```